# Replace Google by Google Search in "What topics can I ask about here?" on Web Apps Help

Tags: discussion

## Request

Replace `Google` by `Google Search` in https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic because this could eventually help the reduce the use of [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) when should be used [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search).

## Details

### As is

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which
>   behaves like an application

### To be

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google Search, or any other website which
>   behaves like an application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with this suggestion, although perhaps Google Search isn't the best example app to use. Not all questions about Google Search are on topic, such as those about search engine optimization.

I suggest something else. Some possible options:

- Yahoo! Mail
- Trello
- Google Maps
- Bing
- YouTube
- Outlook.com
- Draw.io

in addition to the already listed "Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, ..."

Comment: Favouring Trello or YouTube since Gmail covers the "web email" bloc

Comment: @Eight: Seems reasonable to me, although I think we should be cautious about Google being overrepresented.

Comment: I vote for using Trello for replacing "Google" or just, remove "Google" as three examples could be considered enough.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really agree with doing this, although I understand your reasoning behind it.

There are many different types of questions that can be asked regarding Google services, should we list them all out in the on-topic section? e.g. Google Search, Google Apps, Google For Work, Google Docs etc?

Unless the community has a strong opinion on implementing this change, I'd be inclined to leave it as it is.

Comment: What about instead of replacing "Google" by "Google Search" replace "Google" by any other non Google web app in the top of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags like "Trello", "Cognito-Forms", "Github", "Tumblr", "Dropbox" or even simpler just remove "Google" as three examples should be enough?